# How to cancel retrofit request queue in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

In my application i should call one api , **every 1 second** .
But when this seconds is **many time**, my application has freeze and **not call any other apis** !
I want when activity go to `onPause`, cancel all of requests!

**My Codes:**

```
     countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                       if (isLoadLast6Bid) {
                       runLast6Bid(defaultCallApiTime);
                       Log.e("runningLog", "Code : " + isLoadLast6Bid);
}
```

I write below codes for `onResume` and `onPause` :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isLoadLast6Bid = true;
    Log.e("runningLog", "Resume : " + isLoadLast6Bid);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isLoadLast6Bid = false;
    Log.e("runningLog", "Pause : " + isLoadLast6Bid);
}
```

in `onPause` show me **false** for **isLoadlast6Bid**, but in `logCat` show me **call api again**!
For show api logs i use `HttpLoggingInterceptor` !

I used `call.cancel();` in `onPause` method, but again call api. i think store this requests in queue

How can i fix it and **cancel all of request**?

Comment: Call an Http request each second is not a good practice and certainly not a solution . It seems a case of Connection oriented approach A Socket..

Comment: @ADM, yes my friend and i know this! but my CTO says to me i should use api and call this in every second ! but can you help me for this? please my friend, i really need your help

Comment: There is no need to call An API every second when the previous one did not returned yet .. What you can do it whenever you get a response(Error or success both) from API you then schedule next API call again .This way only One call will be running every time .. Again this is not a good practice and it will result in performance degrade, battery drain .. Pass this one to up ..

Comment: @ADM, can you send to me your code for this? please my friend, please